How to get Mac Monterey to send and receive valid HDMI eARC commands to my TV/Monitor
I have a Hisense TV as the external screen for a 2012 Mac Pro running Monterey.
The mac has been  highly upgraded with new cpu board with 12 3.33 Ghz cores, 96 GB ram.
The video card has been replaced with a Sapphire with two display port and two hdmi connectors, and a DVI port.
After some period of inactivity, the Mac stops sending output to the HDMI port.  Then the TV either goes into screen saver mode, or turns off.
I then have to turn the screen on with the TV remote.  It will show an error about "HDMI signal weak or absent" until I hit a key, or startle the mouse.
What I would like to have happen:
When the Mac puts the screen to sleep, the screen sleeps.  When I wake up the mac, the screen wakes up.
All the stuff I find about HDMI-CEC is about using a single remote to control the TV, etc.  I want to reverse this - I want the Mac to control the TV.
HDMI eARC allows for devices to play various roles.  One of the roles is that the TV can either give a "Turn ON command to another peripheral", or alternately, another device can turn on the device.
My TV has this capability. Ideally, I would like to do this without adapters.
How do I get my Mac send these signals to a TV that can accept eARC commands over HDMI?

MacBook Pro or Mac Pro? The Desktop Mac Pro does not come equipped with an HDMI port.

I think both your Mac and TV work as expected: your Mac is configured to put displays to sleep after a certain amount of time, and it does exactly that. Your TV is configured to turn off after a certain period of inactivity, and that's what it does. You can't configure macOS to selectively keep a display "awake". However, your TV, most probably, has a timeout setting to prevent it from turning off. Have you tried setting that timeout to several hours so that it goes to sleep mode but never turns off?

@icondaemon Sapphire  graphics cardupgrade.

Please add this crucial datapoint into your question!
